# Can I safely remove my Git topic branch that has been merged into master?

Tags: git

If I have created and pushed a topic branch that has been merged to master long time ago, can I safely just run `git push origin :foobranch` without fearing that it somehow deletes data that is merged to master or some other branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there are no outstanding commits, its safe. If you want to be sure

```
git checkout master
git merge foobranch
```

This should result in a fast-forward merge (that does not affect the history). If not, maybe there were unmerged commits. However, now you are *completely* safe

```
git branch -d foobranch
git push origin :foobranch
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can safely delete a branch that has been merged into another branch.  Branches are like movable pointers into the commit graph, and if you delete a branch, it's just removing that pointer.  The commit graph remains, and in your case the `master` branch will still contain the history of the branch you've removed.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly safe.

Any commit is linked to a tree (ie, your project files), and potentially, several commits point to the same tree. It is only when no commit links to a tree anymore that it may be garbage collected.

If you still need to recollect it somehow and don't even have a local ref to the commit, there is the reflog, which is cleaned up only after 90 days (I *think*) by default.

Answer (score 1):

deleting a commit or a branch won't affect other commits on other branches, even if that commit was shared among branches, or the branch was merged into other branches.